# Find the area of the larger of the two geometric figures obtained by cutting a cylinder with an axis perpendicular to the bases

Tags: geometry

Given a cylinder of radius R and height H, what is the formula for finding the volume of ​​the larger of the two geometric figures obtained by cutting the cylinder with a plane perpendicular to the bases, and placed at distance (minimum) D from the axis of symmetry of the cylinder, with R > 0, H > 0, 0 < D < R ?

Comment: I think that you should use term plane instead of "an axis"

Comment: Could you maybe show a picture of what you want to happen?

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/GhWQL.jpg) what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area of a circular segment =area of wedge - area of triangle =$\frac{R^{2}}{2}(\theta-\sin\theta)$

angle of wedge = $\theta=2cos^{-1}{\frac{D}{R}}$

Volume=$H\frac{R^{2}}{2}(\theta-\sin\theta)$

Comment: "Area of Wedge" here means [Circular Sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)